# Is there an idiom or slang for "When you put all of your efforts on something but it doesn't even meet the minimums"?

Tags: idioms, slang

I was wondering if there are any idioms for situations when you have tried your best for doing something, but it doesn't even meet the minimums or it's too simple and valueless in comparison with others works.

Comment: There's ***epic fail***

Comment: A valiant but ineffectual effort.

Comment: "Not up to scratch," "sub-par," "substandard," "unacceptable," "insufficient," or just plain "shitty" are each often used in this sense.

Comment: Your efforts are **futile**. Search for synonyms on Google. There are plenty.

Comment: "Sigh, it was all for nothing"

Comment: "vain labour" or "wasted effort".

Comment: @Jim "epic fail" is a great term but doesn't it usually refer to an attempt that has utterly failed in every possible way, and perhaps even missed the point completely?

Comment: @Drew "valiant effort" is a great choice, I think you should work it up into an answer.

Comment: "When your best just ain't good enough."

Comment: "all for naught"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common idiom for futile effort is: *"Trying to hold back the tide with a broom."* (US) (Sorry, I don't have the resources to find its origin - but there's probably someone on this site who can edit this properly.)

Two references:  [John Bartlett, Familiar Quotations](http://www.bartleby.com/100/330.27.html)

> AUTHOR: Sydney Smith (1771–1845)  QUOTATION: In the midst of this
>   sublime and terrible storm [at Sidmouth], Dame Partington, who lived
>   upon the beach, was seen at the door of her house with mop and
>   pattens, trundling her mop, squeezing out the sea-water, and
>   vigorously pushing away the Atlantic Ocean. The Atlantic was roused;
>   Mrs. Partington’s spirit was up. But I need not tell you that the
>   contest was unequal; the Atlantic Ocean beat Mrs. Partington

[Elizabeth Robbins: Staging a Life](https://books.google.com/books?id=2MU7AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT167&lpg=PT167&dq=Trying+to+hold+back+the+tide+with+a+broom&source=bl&ots=NDNHfZ4oiO&sig=JU9A4d8PMjZ60eOqDSIuCoixoH8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivtoSpp9rNAhVEWj4KHcUtAQEQ6AEISzAM#v=onepage&q=Trying%20to%20hold%20back%20the%20tide%20with%20a%20broom&f=false)

> During the reform agitation of 1830-2, the figure of Mrs. Partington
>   had been created, trying in vain to hold back the tide of change with
>   her broom.

Comment: Hope this helps.  My favorite is "Bail the Titanic with a teacup".

Comment: @ab2 - Wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**[...] best wasn't good enough**

1. The song *Just Once* by *James Ingram* has this opening line  (See [You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9lOfmLXafU)) ...

   > I did my best, but I guess **my best wasn't good enough**
2. Another similar song usage in *Anouk*'s [track](http://www.metrolyrics.com/my-best-wasnt-good-enough-lyrics-anouk.html) title:

   > *My Best Wasn't Good Enough*

Answer (score 2):

Your efforts

**Fall short** ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fall-short-of))

> Prove inadequate or insufficient. For example, *His skills fell short of the required standard*.

Answer (score 0):

Ira Glass calls this the **taste gap**:

> All of us who do creative work, we get into it because we have good taste. But there is this gap. For the first couple years you make stuff, it’s just not that good. It’s trying to be good, it has potential, but it’s not. But your taste, the thing that got you into the game, is still killer. And your taste is why your work disappoints you.
>   http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/309485-nobody-tells-this-to-people-who-are-beginners-i-wish